# How to document function custom types in JSDoc (or TypeScript?) and reference them so VSCode IntelliSense works

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I am trying to document custom function types as part of an object, any help would be greatly appreciated:

#### Context of the problem

Here is a simple object declaration with some function properties (addCoordinate, addCoordinateOne, addCoordinateTwo) which we will go over as 3 exhibits, and why none of these work.

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Point
 * @property {number} x - The X Coordinate
 * @property {number} y - The Y Coordinate
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} Shape
 * @property {Point} startCoordinate - the starting coordinate
 * @property {Point[]} coordinates - An array of point coordinates
 * @property {(x:string, y:string) => void} addCoordinate - Updates the point
 * @property {addCoordinateOne} addCoordinateOne - Updates the point
 * @property {addCoordinateTwo} addCoordinateTwo - Updates the point
 */

/** @type {Shape} */
const square = {}
```

##### Exhibit A

```
@property {(x:string, y:string) => void} addCoordinate - Updates the point
```

This works fully, but isn't reusable like I need.

[image: Exhibit A]

##### Exhibit B

```
/**
 * @typedef {Function} addCoordinateOne
 * @param {string} X
 * @param {string} Y
 */
```

This *sort of* works, as it detects the custom function type. But it doesn't parse parameters properly. I made sure to follow the documentation for the `@typedef` tag:
https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html

[image: Exhibit B]

##### Exhibit C

```
/**
 * @function addCoordinateTwo
 * @param {string} X
 * @param {string} Y
 */
```

This fails completely. Despite being the recommended approach by JSDoc's `@function` documentation.
https://jsdoc.app/tags-function.html

#### The Question

Is there any way I could get Exhibit B or C working like Exhibit A?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change Exhibit A to a typedef:

```js
/** @typedef {(x:string, y:string) => void} addCoordinate */
```

Edit: Or more verbosely, you can use the [`@callback`](https://jsdoc.app/tags-callback.html) tag:

```js
/** 
 * @callback addCoordinate
 * @param {number} x - The x coordinate
 * @param {number} y - The y coordinate 
 * @returns {void}
 */
```

Then reuse as needed:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Point
 * @property {number} x - The X Coordinate
 * @property {number} y - The Y Coordinate
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} Shape
 * @property {Point} startCoordinate - the starting coordinate
 * @property {Point[]} coordinates - An array of point coordinates
 * @property {addCoordinate} addCoordinate - Updates the point
 * @property {addCoordinate} addCoordinateOne - Updates the point
 * @property {addCoordinate} addCoordinateTwo - Updates the point
 */
```

### Result:

If using the shorthand syntax, no paramater descriptions are available.
[image: vs code hover showing expected Intellisense hint]

If using the `@callback` syntax, descriptions are provided for each paramater:
[image: vs code hover showing Intellisense hint with param description]

Comment: why don't you get an error `Expected 2 arguments, got 0`

Comment: That's... not what I expected, but I'm amazed it works haha. That's fantastic. Will award accepted answer if nothing else comes up in a few days. Was looking for something using the extended `@param` syntax to be able to document an explanation of each parameter. Thanks Matt.

Comment: Edited the answer as I also found there is a @callback syntax which works like typedef.

Comment: That solves my problem, thanks @MattSchlosser!